# Django admin panel app model list_display not showing

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin-filters

Here is my code

```
from django.contrib import admin

from farmer.models import *

class listAllFarmer(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'code')
    admin.site.register(allFarmers, listAllFarmer)
```

if I write this only it works

```
from django.contrib import admin

from farmer.models import *
admin.site.register(allFarmers)
```

Comment: the last line `admin.site.register(allFarmers, listAllFarmer)` , should be outside of the class

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. It works. I forgot write the line outside the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `admin.site.register` outside the class:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from farmer.models import *

class listAllFarmer(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'code')

admin.site.register(allFarmers, listAllFarmer)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. It works. I forgot write the line outside the class